# QrCode aparece gerado como imagem incorreta

Tags: php, qrcode

Comecei a procurar por bibliotecas para gerar qr codes e acabei me deparando com esta: https://github.com/endroid/qr-code, me pareceu tranquila de aplicar e portanto optei por ela (E por ser em php).

O problema é que ao gerar o código a resposta que obtenho é esta:
[image: erro geração qrcode]

Alguém que já seja mais familiarizado com a biblioteca ou que tenha alguma ideia do porque de o qr code não estar sendo mostrado corretamente saberia me explicar como concertar?

Será que apliquei algo de forma errada, preciso ativar um plug-in específico, algo assim?

Seguem os códigos abaixo. Agradeço qualquer colaboração

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Teste Qr</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

```
<h1>
    É pra ter um QR Code logo abaixo ;)
</h1>

<img src="getCode.php" alt="qr code">
```

E o arquivo gerador:

```
<?php 

require_once( 'src/QrCode.php' );

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

$qr = new QrCode();

$qr
    ->setText( "Hello There" );
    ->setSize( 200 );
    ->Render();
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem vários erros com o seu código que não está a detectar porque está a usar o getCode.php como src da imagem, se invocar directamente o getCode.php no browser por certo que os va identificar.

Este código funciona apenas estou o autoloader.

*getCode.php*

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
$qr = new QrCode();
$qrCode = new QrCode('Hello There');
header('Content-Type: ' . $qrCode->getContentType());
echo $qrCode->writeString();

?>
```

Comment: Apliquei o seu código e o output seguiu igual

Comment: Invoque o script getCode.php e indique que erros estão a ser produzidos

Comment: O único problema é que a imagem do qr code segue igual, ele não aparece na página.

Comment: O código que apresentei funciona,  pode não ter o relatório de erros ativo no PHP e portanto não vê nenhum erro

Comment: Perdão pela noobada, mas como eu ativo esse relatório?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Acabei nem precisando ativar para encontrar um erro, na pasta extraída do .ZIP não existe nenhum "vendor/autoload.php"

Comment: Como referi eu estou a usar o composer uma sistema de gestão pacotes e dependências para php

Comment: Utilizei o composer e agora está dando certo, muito obrigado